# In String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(String, String), where is the function compare(String, String) defined?

Tags: android

In String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(String, String), where is the function compare(String, String) defined?

[image: In String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(String, String), where is the function compare(String, String) defined?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` is an implementation of the Comparator Interface. This is implemented within the String class. Here is the whole Comparator from the String.java file.

```
public static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                                     = new CaseInsensitiveComparator();
private static class CaseInsensitiveComparator
        implements Comparator<String>, java.io.Serializable {
    // use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.2.2 for interoperability
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8575799808933029326L;

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int n1 = s1.length();
        int n2 = s2.length();
        int min = Math.min(n1, n2);
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
            if (c1 != c2) {
                c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
                c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
                if (c1 != c2) {
                    c1 = Character.toLowerCase(c1);
                    c2 = Character.toLowerCase(c2);
                    if (c1 != c2) {
                        // No overflow because of numeric promotion
                        return c1 - c2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return n1 - n2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After asking the question, I found that in String.java file too.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE_INSENSETIVE_ORDER` is a static field of `String` class of type `Comperator`.
it comtains the `compare()` method

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)